# Updating single files (aspx / js) in an Add-in fails

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2015

I created the simplest possible SharePoint Add-in using the default template in Visual Studio 2015. (SharePoint-hosted)

I deployed the Add-in to the SharePoint Online site of my Office 365 Developer Trial Account.

After that I change a single character in the "Default.aspx" file.

When I now hit F5, I get the following messages in the output window:

> Skipping deployment step because a pre-deployment command is not
>   specified.
>
> **Unexpected error when directly deploying file**
>   c:\users\matthias\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\QuickTest\QuickTest\Pages\Default.aspx.
>
> **Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.**
>
> Uninstall SharePoint Add-in:
>
> ...

This results in a complete uninstall / install cycle, which is way too slow for rapid development. ;) (1 - 2 minutes)

I [heard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScyUjSJYHtI#t=24m33s) that it is also possible to live update a file during a debug session by simply saving the file. This failed too.

Are there any permissions I need to setup to make this work?

Comment: try FastDeploy plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason for such behavior is disabled scripting capabilities.
To make it work you need to enable scripting capabilities on your tenant.
More info you can find here - [Turn scripting capabilities on or off](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f).

In short you need to *Allow users to run custom script on personal sites* and *Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites*

Some advises for rapid development. You have different options, you can select the one most suitable for you (from simple to more complex):

1. In VS press F5 for debugging. Now when you are saving `.aspx` or `.js` or `.css`, etc. VS will upload that file to app (**not** host) web automatically.
2. Install [SPFastDeploy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCurranMVP.SPFastDeploy) VS extension. It allows you to upload your modified files from VS to app web. Pretty cool extenstion.
3. If you familiar with `gulp`, you can use [`gulp-spsave`](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/gulp-spsave) or [`gulp-spsync`](https://github.com/wictorwilen/gulp-spsync). This gulp plugins allow you to upload anything to anywhere in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Kai's answer I found a solution.

Instead of turning on the scripting capabilities I created a new site collection with the developer template and use that for my development. This fixes the permission problem.

I was using the root site collection before, for which the scripting capability is turned off by default. (see link in Kai's post)

Comment: Who is Kai?! and where is his answer?

Answer (score 0):

For those using Visual Studio 2017:

I wasn't able to get the live-update of files to work at all.

So I ended up using Visual Studio 2015 and it worked just fine

For 2015 you'll need the office developer tools: http://aka.ms/officedevtoolsforvs2015